# PHP- No option to authenticate user in firebase-php

Tags: firebase, laravel-5, firebase-authentication

I am trying to identify if I have set security rules in the users node like below

```
Users:
  $uid:
    write: auth.uid != null,
    read : auth.uid != null,
```

What I don't understand how to authenticate users with PHP. As document doesn't provide me any sign-in functionality as in JavaScript .Because until and unless I authenticate the user. It doesn't allow me to update values in user's nodes due to security rules.

```
Using laravel/firebase-php V4.29
Firebase SDK 8.4
Language - PHP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication code runs client-side, so in the browser or in the native app. The PHP code that you have runs on the server, where you can't sign in a user. The server-side code itself runs with administrative privileges, as you [configure it with a service account](https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase#configuration).

If you are interacting with the database directly from the client-side code too, you'll want to include the JavaScript SDK in your client-side, and sign in the user there as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start).

If you're interacting with the database from the server-side PHP code, that should already work as using a service account means your code bypasses the security rules. If this isn't working for you, please edit your question to show how you configure the SDK.

Comment: Oh ok. Does it mean If I am fetching the messages from firebase using JavaScript I need to authenticate the user with JS only?

Comment: And what If I authenticate the user with PHP by upgrading the package but initialize the database with JS. It wouldn't work, right?

Comment: If you want to access the database from the client-side JavaScript, you need to sign the user in with the client-side JavaScript SDK too.